# CORS - ...does not support http method 'OPTIONS'

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, cors, owin

When CORS is configured (and seemingly working) it still returns a 405 for the OPTIONS verb.

CORS is configured via the Owin NuGet package, `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` and it seems to return the correct headers.

I notice the issue in Fiddler when I fake a preflight OPTIONS request. The headers come back properly when I propose that I am calling from an allowed domain and they are correctly absent if I propose some other domain - its working.

But why the 405?

`HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: GET,PUT,DELETE
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:12345
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 01 Oct 2015 18:59:32 GMT
Content-Length: 96`

`<Error><Message>The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'.</Message></Error>`

Note the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is present, so I guess the browser will be okay, or will the browser be 'put off' by the negative 405?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst working on another problem, I reverse engineered the whole of `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` to step through it.

It turns out that if the middleware has handled the OPTIONS request then it should return a 2xx and indeed, with the new knowledge of exactly what the middleware needed to see in a request to determine that it was a CORS preflight request, I was able to fake one in Fiddler and get a 2xx.

So, if you get a 405, then double-check.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may check first allowed verb's setting on the configurations of IIS.

refer to http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/verbs

- web.config example

  `<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
        <security>
           <requestFiltering>
              <verbs applyToWebDAV="false">
                 <add verb="PUT" allowed="false" />
              </verbs>
           </requestFiltering>
        </security>
     </system.webServer>
  </configuration>`

Comment: It's not webdavs in the question but this is nevertheless a clue to my version of this problem, in which erstwhile friends are no longer talking with a 405 response to options where once things were OK.